# Why use "value" but not "ref" for property value in spring.net config

Tags: c#, .net, spring.net

Recently when I read the Spring.net's [documentation](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/index.html). I found there is one place that is quite confusing to me. In 5.3.2.1.1, the doc said as below:

```
<object id="theTargetObject" type="...">     . . . </object>

<object id="theClientObject" type="...">   
    <property name="targetName"> 
        <idref object="theTargetObject"/>
    </property>
</object>
```

> This above object definition snipped is exactly equivalent (at runtime) to
>   the following snippit:

```
<object id="theTargetObject" type="...">    . . . </object>

<object id="theClientObject" type="...">      
      <property name="targetName" value="theTargetObject"/>
</object>
```

I think there is a mistake here, in the second code snippet, the attribute "value" should be "ref" as its value refers to the theTargetObject and not a raw string value. Am I right? Thank you for anyone who is verifying that.

Comment: What is the *problem* with that snippet?  You've stated what you think the solution should be, but not what problem that solution is trying to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did test and find in that scenario using value is not correct, it should be "ref" or "idref".

Comment: If that's the case you should contact the author(s) and point that mistake out to them.